# Regular expression to allow numbers, characters or alphanumeric but not empty strings or special character

Tags: java, regex

I have inputs as number,alphamumeric char etc. I have build regular expression to validate this but failing to validate empty string.(empty string should not be allowed)
here is my regex,

```
(^([A-Za-z]|[0-9])+$)
```

Can this be improved with above requirement?

Comment: put the `[0-9]` in the same block as the `[A-Za-z]`: `[A-Za-z0-9]`. Also using `Matcher.matches` instead of `find` negates the need for `^` and `$` so your regex could be simply `[A-Za-z0-9]+`. However, keeping the start and end markers makes the regex more explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need this regex:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

This will only allow alphabets (uppercase or lowercase) and digits. Empty string will NOT be allowed since regex will match for input of 1 or more in length.

Comment: well its not working for me its allowing empty fields, 
i tested here http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html with different input fields

Comment: @Sohan: You're not testing it correct, I just tested and it worked, test it again.

Comment: @Sohan: See this demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/YEWdUsRIIj Only first 3 lines match but bottom 2 (including empty string) don't.

Comment: if u see the link where i have tested,if one of the field is left empty if does nothing and no reslt is shown .Same is in my case. If field is left empty if shld validate and throw error

Comment: No result shown without highlight on Rubular means match FAILED :)

Comment: Thanks there must be problem with jasper java class i need to raise ticket with them

Comment: Great, If you think this answer helped you in solving your problem pls mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have inputs as number,alphamumeric char etc. I have build regular
>   expression to validate this but failing to validate empty
>   string.(empty string should not be allowed) here is my regex,

The regex you posted already disallows the empty string. But you should combine the [A-Za-z] and [0-9] using `\w` like this:

`^(\w)+$`

If you want it to ALSO accept the empty string you could use:

`^(\w)*$`